# TFS Dev to Release merging

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, merge

I have two branches from trunk in TFS that say Dev and Release. Right now I want to move to release mode. How do I move my code in Dev to Release branch that is empty right now. And how do I reverse merge changes from Release into Development later when I make fixes in Release. I read in TFS2010, it makes it easy to merge back and forth by two or three clicks. Can some one comment on this and also on how I can accomplish the above things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on the release branch and select Merge. Select the dev branch and the changesets you want and et viola.

Ahhh I see. When did you branch?

You first need to branch all the code in dev over. Then checkin the release branch with all the code in it.

So if you've already branched (empty release branch) and the code is not in release yet, rename the release branch, then rebranch dev  to a new release branch. Then all the code will come over.

From then onwards you can merge from release to dev easily.

Comment: I followed your comment... but The target branch drop down is empty and I cannot pick anything.